# Average over a field in DictField in Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I am using Mongoengine and in one collection I have a DictField(). Documents contain entries for the DictField like -

```
{'load_time' : 134, 'show_time' : 126}
```

Now I want to find the average over load_time for the DictField(). How can I do this? The average function of mongoengine allows to average over document fields only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very familiar with MongoEngine, but ... 
It says in [the api reference](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.5/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.average) that you can "use dot-notation to refer to embedded document fields"...

Will `average( "yourdictfieldname.load_time" )` work for this?

Comment: I don't think this will work. I'm under the impression that this can be used when the Document has an EmbeddedDocument and not a DictField. Anyway, I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: Shucks.  Once I read there's a distinction between "EmbeddedDocumentField" and "DictField", I was afriad it wouldn't.  :(  I guess if there were enough structure to the data you could convert this Dict -- or some part of it -- to a Document field, so as to perform this average.  But I imagine there's a good reason you haven't done that already.

Comment: Yes. Actually, I am using MongoEngine, and the number of keys in the DictField actually varies and might also increase in the future. And as I'm using mongoengine, one needs to have a predefined structure (fields) must be defined beforehand and can't vary. Hence, the dict field was used. Well, having not found an answer I coded the logic to find the average and stuff - inefficient but does the work.

Comment: @Siddharth - Actually just because you've defined some fields before hand doesn't mean you can't add additional fields later. MongoDB handles this just fine and you can define "default" values for any fields that don't exist in the database (for your older data). If you don't set a default, those fields will simply be null for any documents that don't have them.